# Memory Allocation char* and char[]

Tags: c++

What is the difference between these two in terms of memory allocation.

```
char *p1 = "hello"; 
char p2[] = "hello";
```

Comment: The first should be `const char*`!

Comment: `p1` takes 4 or 8 bytes (required to store a memory address) which is platform dependent. `p2` takes 6 bytes (= 5 bytes for string `hello` + 1 byte for null terminating character).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The first one creates a *pointer* variable (four or eight bytes of storage depending on the platform) and stores a *location* of a string literal there, The second one creates an *array* of six characters (including zero string terminator byte) and copies the literal there.

You should get a compiler warning on the first line since the literal is `const`.

Comment: Where exactly is the string literal stored? Is it in heap?

Comment: The string literal is commonly stored in a region of memory separate from both the stack and the (`new`/`delete`-managed) heap. Depending on your platform, this region may be copy-protected, so writing to it will crash the program.

Comment: If I'm not wrong `p2` is also nothing but a pointer variable. Isn't it? So allocation of _four or eight bytes of storage depending on the platform_ should happen in case of `p2` as well. This piece of code `p1 = p2; 
 printf("%c" , *(p1 + 4));` prints `o`. So the only difference left is that fact that there is a null terminating character in case of declaration of `p2`.

Answer (score 9):

The first one is a non-const pointer to const (read-only) data, the second is a non-const array.

Comment: So is char *p1 = "hello" equivalent to char const *p1 = "hello"?

Comment: @Mahatma: yes, and this is also the same as the more readable and intuitive version: `const char *p1 = "hello"`.

Comment: @Mahatma: yes, but the first is dangerous: without a `const` qualification, there is no compiler protection against attempting to modify the string literal, giving undefined behaviour.

Comment: Will there be a null terminating character in case of both `p1` and `p2` declarations?

Comment: @RBT: yes, the string literal initialiser guarantees that.

Comment: Ok. Cool. So that means the two code blocks that asker has posted have absolutely no difference in the number of number of bytes allocated (memory taken by string + null terminating character) and both have a pointer variable each which points to starting of the allocated string. The difference you have suggested is bang on target. I couldn't digest the accepted answer on this thread thoroughly. I come from a C# background and couldn't differentiate between string literal (the read-only const thingy) and array of characters :(.

Comment: You got it! ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Since the first one is a non-const pointer to const (read-only) data, the second is a non-const array, as Paul said, you can write:

```
p2[2]='A'; //changing third character - okay
```

But you cannot write:

```
p1[2]='A';//changing third character - runtime error!
```

Comment: The second case is actually worse than a compilation error; the compiler will most likely accept it, giving undefined runtime behaviour.

Comment: That's not true- he won't get a compile error as the string literal isn't const. He will however get UB.

Comment: That's not fixed. That code produces UB, which is not a run-time error. It is undefined behaviour. Now, in reality on most platforms, you will get a run-time error (SIGSEGV on Unix variants, Access Violation on Windows). However, the Standard says nothing about this and since he didn't mention his platform, you can't assume it.

Comment: @Nawaz Will there be a null terminating character in case of both p1 and p2 declarations? Also will _the additional allocation of four or eight bytes of storage depending on the platform_ would happen in case of p2 as well (same as p1) because p2 is also a pointer in the end?

Comment: @RBT: 1) **yes**, both `p1` and `p2` will be null-terminating. 2) `p1` takes exactly `sizeof(p1)` bytes of memory which stores the address of the first element of *static* array (as defined by the string literal `"hello"`). However, `p2` is *an array*, **not a pointer**, created out of the string-literal `"hello"`..and it takes `sizeof(p2)` bytes of memory. Note also that `sizeof(p1)` and `sizeof(p2)` could be different, and in this case, it would be a different for sure.

Comment: .... I also see what you might possibly mean by *"additional allocation"*. There is no "additional allocation" as such. The string literal `"hello"` resides in some other memory, and that is *not* a part of `p1` in any way. `p1` just happens to points to it. Nothing more than that. Let me know if that clarified your doubt.

Comment: Yes. `p1`'s "hello" will reside on some other memory area as it can't be modified there after which is possible in case of heap allocation.I'm just trying to understand the number of bytes consumed in two cases assuming these are the only lines of code in my console C application. For p1 - bytes pertaining to size of pointer+5 bytes for string +1 byte for null terminating character. For p2 - 5 bytes for string + 1 byte for null terminating character. That's why I was saying that p1 being a pointer causes _additional memory allocation_ which is not the case for p2 which will get stored on stack

Comment: @RBT: For `p1`, it is just the size of the pointer (which is either `4` or `8`). Nothing else.  For `p2`, it is `6` bytes. In case of `p1`, there is **no** *additional memory allocation*.   Take another example: `int x = 10; int *y=&x;`. Here the size of `y` is just the size of the pointer (which is either `4` or `8`). There is no additional/other allocation for `y`.

Comment: I was trying to compare as per OP who asked `difference between these two in terms of memory allocation` which is why I'm saying p2 is taking 6 bytes (character array) and p1 - (`4` or `8` bytes for pointer storing a memory address) + the read-only string literal pointed by p1 (6 bytes). Space taken by a pointer to store address or a read-only string literal which goes to a specialized program area are also sort of memory allocation. Isn't it? or I'm getting the verbiage wrong. Pardon me if I'm talking silly as I'm from C# world trying to learn C.

Comment: @RBT: It is technically **wrong** to say that the memory of *"read-only string literal pointed to be p1"* is part of `p1`. Take this example, `char const *x = "Rasik"; char const *y = "Rasik";`.  Now print the address of both `x` and `y`; they will be same (see [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4ce53e7f1ebab29c)). What does that mean? You **cannot** say `"Rasik"` is part of memory allocated to both `x` and `y`. **That is wrong**. `"Rasik"` is a different object.... and `x` and `y` points to *that* object. There can be more pointers pointing the same object. Makes sense now?

Comment: ... as for your C# background, I think I know that. I had worked for 1E for 1 month ;). And yes, C#/Java/Python/etc makes few concepts of C++ really difficult to understand.

Comment: @RBT, @Nawaz, they call C++ difficult. C# thread function can be static or non-static (how). Lambdas have no capture specification. There is no `const` in C#. There is nothing equivalent to `static_assert` - impossible. They enjoy with run-time exceptions. Only 1 left with 1e ;)

Comment: @Ajay: Well, C# has been made *simple* by cutting of lots of features that C++ has. C++ is *the* most complicated language (and there is a rationale for it), is a known fact.

Answer (score 0):

The first line is assigning a string(an array of characters) to a **constant** (meaning you cant change the value without getting a segmentation fault) array of characters , char* essentially points to a character ( or array of bytes if its was allocated multiple character ) in memory. In the second line you are creating an array of characters ( think the same thing as the first as ,they both point to a place in memory where everything is located) , but this time , you can **change** the values being held within without getting a segmentation fault , as it is **non-constant** .