# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in strtok

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Memory Allocation char* and char[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680431/memory-allocation-char-and-char)

Why does the following program give a Segmentation fault in run-time ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>

main()
{
    char * str = "Have a. nice, day :)";
    char * ptr;

    ptr = strtok( str, " .,");

    printf("%s",ptr);
 }
```

But if I use char str[] = "Have a. nice, day :)"; it gives me the output. Why is that i get the error even though strtok definition is char* strcpy( char * , const char * ) ???~

Answer (score 5):

`strtok` modifies the argument, `str` points to a string literal, modifying a string literal causes undefined behavior. Initializing a non-const `char*` with a string literal is in fact deprecated.

When you write `str[]`, `str` becomes a mutable array initialized with the string.

Answer (score 0):

strtok modifies the string passed to it.  I suspect it has something to do with char * = "literal string" giving you a pointer to the string in the .data section, while char[] = "literal string" allocates a buffer on the stack, and copies the initial contents from the .data section.