# char * and char[]

Tags: c++

Why is this right ?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char *s="raman";
    char *t="rawan";
    s=t;
    cout<<s;

return 0;
}
```

But this is wrong?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char s[]="raman";
    char t[]="rawan";
    s=t;
    cout<<s;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Define "right" and "wrong".

Comment: You can not assign an array after initialization but you can assign a pointer.

Comment: [How do I use arrays in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c) is a good read.

Comment: The first is not right — string literals are `const char*`, not `char*`. Assigning them to `char*` is dangerous.

Comment: As @Cat Plus Plus, rightly says it is dangerous and compiler gives you a warning for doing that, which you ignored. **NEVER** ignore compiler warnings they are a indication of problems you might face in future.

Comment: Save yourself a lot of potential headaches and use `std::string`. It exists for good reasons.

Comment: @Cat Plus Plus: No, string literals are `const char[N]`, where N is the length of the literal plus 1 (to allow for the terminating `'\0'`).  In most contexts, though, they decay to `const char*`, with the value being a pointer to the string's first character.  For example, `sizeof "hello, world"` yields 13, *not* the size of a pointer.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Details. The point is they're `const`.

Comment: @Cat Plus Plus: Yes, the fact that they're `const` is important, and it's why the first program gets a warning.  But the distinction between pointers and arrays is critically important, not a mere detail.

Comment: As a side note: If you read your warnigns you will see that `char *s="raman";` is depricated it should actually be `char const *s="raman";`

Comment: In short, neither is right. The problem with the first is `char *s="raman";` This gets a warning but more importantly, it is undefined behavior. The problem with the second is `s=t;`, which is out-and-out illegal.

Comment: Just a reminder, you haven't accepted an answer to this question.

Comment: @gautam: You haven't accepted an answer to this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first example assigns an pointer to another which is valid.

The second example assigns an array to another array which in not allowed in C & C++ both.

---

**[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c)** excellent C++ FAQ entry and **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680431/memory-allocation-char-and-char)** answer should be a good read for you.

Answer (score 15):

In the first example, `s=t` does a pointer assignment.  In the second, `s=t` tries to assign a pointer value (resulting from the implicit conversion, or "decay", of the array expression `t`) to an array object.  C++ doesn't permit array assignments.

C and C++ happen to be very similar in this area; section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/) covers the relationship between arrays and pointers very well.

Comment: Just an FYI: I meant to decline your last flag (the one that says an answer is deliberately deceptive), but I accidentally marked it helpful. Flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer.

Comment: @NullUserException: Understood, thanks for the notice.  I think the situation has been resolved anyway.  You can delete your comment if you like.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what the other guys said:

Contrary to popular belief, arrays are actually not pointers. They just share a lot of similarities when working with them and have a couple of implicit conversions to pointers which is why it's easy to work with them as if they are pointers.

Arrays are a standalone feature of (C and) C++. It doesn't behave exactly like a pointer would.

For example, it's possible to allocate array objects on the stack, which is not possible when you allocate objects using new (which returns a pointer) and pointers.

And the example that you showed is another one: You can't use arrays as if they are pointers. But you can use pointers to point to a continuous piece of memory (array).

Answer (score 1):

Array name is a const pointer. meaning, when you declare an array, the name is a pointer, which cannot be altered.

Answer (score 1):

`char *s` means:
address and value both are not constant.

```
const char *s:
```

value is constant, not address.

```
const char * const s;
```

address and value both are constant.

```
char *s[]
```

is an array. Array base address is always contant. You can not change the base address of it, that is not allowed in c.