# cin/cout with char[]

Tags: c++, char, cin

I am trying to build my overall expertise in C++ coming from VBA, so please forgive any glaring issues with my code... Using this simple program below, I am getting unexpected output.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
char f[]="", c[]="";
std::cin >> f;
std::cout << f << std::endl;
std::cin >> c;
std::cout << f << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

When run, this is my result:

> ABC (input)
>   f - ABC (output)
>   DEF (input)
>   f - EF (output)

Also tried as:

> ABC DEF (input)
>   f - ABC (output)
>   f - EF (output)

I would expect that the output would be the same for both lines, since I *THINK* I'm only reading into `f` once. Moreover, if I am taking the `cin` and applying it to `f`, why does the first attempt read the entire string (`ABC`) while the second attempt is missing the `D`?

I tried also printing the result using this code, but the same problem occurs, so I'm assuming here that it's a problem with the `cin` and not `cout`.

```
for (j=0;j<3;j++) {
    std::cout << f[j];
}
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Doing some research, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6930859/698590), which looked promising, but when I changed my declaration from `char f[]` to `char *f`, I ended up with SEGFAULTs on the `cin`, while `const char *f` wouldn't even compile.

I am fumbling blindly here and would appreciate some guidance on how to correctly use `cin` and/or `char` arrays.

To reiterate my question: **Why does the output `std::cout << f << std::endl;`, while not explicitly reassigning a value, vary in this way?**

Comment: If you want this behaviour, use `std::string`. For a char array, it needs to be long enough to hold the input.

Comment: Never use `istream::operator>>` with char arrays, it is inherently unsafe. (unless you are using a stream where you know the max size of the data, such as a stringstream which you passed the string to yourself)

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Would it be preferred then to cin>>string, then use string.c_str()?

Comment: @Gaffi: To the first, yes.  To the second, I don't see why `c_str()` has to come into it.  Are you interfacing with a C library?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley No, I am merely trying to iterate over the characters of the string, and figured `char[]` was a good fit for that. I saw some resources online use `c_str` as a means to convert from one to the other. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You can iterate over the characters of a `std::string` in the same way you can over a char array, using `operator[]`, which is overloaded for `std::string`.  There are other ways too, such as `std::string::iterator`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
char f[]="", c[]="";
```

is equivalent to

```
char f[1]="", c[1]="";
```

i.e. it declares both `f` and `c` as arrays of one character (namely `NUL` or `\0`, the null terminator).

In other words, you're reading into both arrays past their end, which could work perfectly, could do very strange things (like you're seeing), could crash, or could make purple elephants erupt from your monitor next Tuesday.

Comment: Is it preferred then to use `f[256]` or some other larger value? I tried this, and it looks like it works, but there are other suggestions in the comments indicating I shouldn't even be using `char[]` in the first place.

Comment: @Gaffi: Right: any number you pick, the user can enter a string that's larger. This is a textbook example of a buffer overflow vulnerability. If you read into an `std::string`, you can write out that `std::string` without ever putting anything into a `char[]`. Otherwise, you probably need to figure out how big the input string is and dynamically allocate an array to fit it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should use the `getline` function.  There are two versions of it...

One is in the C++ standard library and is used this way:

```
std::string s;
// the following returns the stream that you give
// (the cast is non-functional, it's there to show the type)
(istream&)getline(cin, s);
```

The `string` object is nice for this because it dynamically sizes itself to hold whatever you receive.

The other `getline` is in the standard C library, at least on Mac OS X (run `man 3 getline` for more) and it uses `FILE*` instead of streams.  That version is capable of dynamically reallocating a `char` array if you want it to, but you don't have to use it that way.

Comment: Lose the cast, otherwise this is great advice.

Comment: The second getline you are referring to is not part of the standard C library.  There is another (c++ standard) getline though, the [istream member function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) version.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include < iostream >

int main() {
    char f[]="";
    char c[]="";
```

Try these, it solve the problem for me ;D