# Why I can use array that initiated with 0 size: Char ch[0];

Tags: c++, arrays, char

This is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    char ch[0];
    cin >> ch;
    cout << ch;
    return 0;
}
```

input1:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza
```

output1:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza
```

(working fine, but I don't know why)

input2:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzab
```

output2:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzab_
```

(request an input)

input3:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabc
```

output3:
(runtime error)

when output2 request an input, and we put input2,
the output is same output2 (with request an input again),
and output1 or output2 will appear too when we put input1 or input2 in there

Can someone explain this phenomenon? Why it happens?

Comment: **Undefined Behavior**

Comment: You are defining an array with _zero_ elements, it is a wonder the compiler doesn't complain. Next thing you do is to write into that array, which makes no sense. The compiler probably just assumes space has been reserved and your program writes willy-nilly, and the writes by sheer bad luck normally don't step on anything vital. Then you get the stuff from said zero-length array (presumably the compiler just fetches whatever was written out of bounds before). Bletch!

Comment: It doesn't work you just got lucky twice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [cin/cout with char\[\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381043/cin-cout-with-char)

Comment: yeah, it's have a same problem and answer, but different question, so sorry to create duplicate

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An array of size 0 is not valid:

> If the constant-expression (5.19) is present, it shall be an integral constant expression and its value shall be greater than zero.

If your compiler accepts it, it is merely a non-standard extension. GCC accepts it but will issue a diagnostic if you add the `-pedantic` option:

```
warning: ISO C++ forbids zero-size array ‘arr’ [-pedantic]
```

Nonetheless, reading into an non-standard array of zero size will undoubtedly give you undefined behaviour.

Comment: Was just about to say this. Well put.

Comment: @jrok Yeah, my brain is letting me phrase that correctly... I give up!

Comment: @sftrabbit: +1 and comment deleted ;)

Comment: @sftrabbit I'm sorry, but I dont understand the meaning "extension" in
"it is merely a non-standard extension" ?

Comment: @malioboro The C++ standard defines what C++ is. A C++ compiler should be compliant with the standard. The standard allows for compilers to have "extensions", provided that they do not alter the behaviour of any well-formed program. Any extension is not part of the C++ standard.

Comment: ok, thanks, it's clear now, your answer and @NikBougalis ' s answer actually is accepted answers :)

Answer (score 2):

As stfrabbit points out the standard *explicitly* forbids the declaration of an array of size zero. But `gcc` allows this sort of thing as an extension for [reasons](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html) which we won't get into.

So what's happening? Well, when it's time to look for acceptable overloads of `operator>>` and `operator<<` the compiler treats `char ch[0]` as `char[]` which then degenerates into `char *`.

It finds an overload for `char *` and invokes it. So you are now thrashing random memory (starting at the address of `ch` which is is who-knows-what). If you weren't in undefined behavior land before, you're in undefined behavior land now.

And once you're in undefined behavior land, *anything* goes: the program could cause the Universe to start contracting or it could cause *one... hundred... million... dollars* to magically appear in your bank account.

Or it could just crash.

Comment: ok, thanks, it's clear now, your answer and @stfrabbit ' s answer actually is accepted answers :)

Answer (score 1):

Basically `char ch[0]`; is a defined address in memory. 
You pass it to Cin It starts writing at characters from input to it.
You then pass that same address and it tries to make sense of it.
Essentially print every character until it runs in to a 0.

You'd have to do some deep investigation as to why you are seeing this behaviour, but it would be a complete waste of time. The behaviour is undefined theres no guarantee it's in any way repeatable.

Answer (score 1):

Most compilers will just set the array to have a real start address but will not take any space so subsequent variables on the stack or in a structure would start at the same address they would have if the 0 sized array didn't exist at all. This is quite often used as a last member of a structure where the structure is padded when allocated by n bytes. The array being the last member can then be indexed to access that padding without pointer math.

eg.

```
struct foo
{
    int a;
    int b;
    char c[0];
};

foo* f = malloc(sizeof(foo) + 50);

for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
    f->c[i] = 57;
```

sizeof foo is most likely 8 but it doesn't matter because c is the end address of that structure, regardless of how the structure is byte aligned/padded.

Some Win32 API's leverage this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have array which can store the input value, this definitely cannot handle.

```
char ch[0];
```

This definitely a `Segmentation` fault.

```
$./a.out 
12345678901234567890
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

You need to define `ch` as big as you required as input.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting classical buffer overrun problem. Though it is not compliant to define array of zero size, what is happening, is that you are getting a variable on the stack with the size of default alignment (4 or 8 usually).

So when you start reading into that variable, you put data on the stack, and it starts overriding your stack frame. This is not too visible immediately, however it destroys you returns address.

So the code executes read (fine), and then write (which is is also fine), and then tries to return. If the return address has been destroyed, you get segmentation fault. Otherwise this may continue unnoticed. The reason you don't get output in the last example, is due to buffered output - the program doesn't get a change to flush the buffers before quit (as it is done after return from main).

Here is an example, how you can see your code overrides the stack data:

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    int dummy1 = 0xCDCDCDCDCDCDCDCD;
    int dummy2 = 0xCDCDCDCDCDCDCDCD;

    char badvar[0];

    cin >> badvar;
    cout << badvar << endl;
    cout << dummy1 << endl;
    cout << dummy2 << endl;
    cout << flush;

    return 0;
}
```